# Debug Pyinstaller OS X app with --windowed mode

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to package a wxPython GUI with pyinstaller, but I've run into some problems that I need to debug.

A minimal wxPython app with all of my dependencies runs correctly, but my GUI is more complicated and I don't know which part is breaking.  Pyinstaller runs through to completion with minimal errors, so I was hoping to use the --debug flag.

From the [Pyinstaller docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html):

> Normally the debug progress messages go to standard output. If the --windowed option is used when bundling a Windows app, they are displayed as MessageBoxes. For a --windowed Mac OS app they are not displayed.

Is there a way around this?  I'm partially debugging by temporarily updating my program to redirect stdout/stderr to a file, but it would be great to know if there is a way to get the Pyinstaller debug messages on Mac with the --windowed option.